# Can to-infinitives be used after the verb “dislike”?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, catenative-verbs

Can *to*-infinitives follow the verb *dislike*? I know they can follow the verb *like* that way, but what about *dislike*? I ask because my school grammar textbook says the following:

> > #### The verb *dislike* takes only the gerund form of verbs after it.

There is something amiss about that statement. As far as I know (mind you, my knowledge may not go too far), *dislike* can be followed by both *to*-infinitives and gerunds. I have read some writings where the to-infinitive construction has been used (giving specific instances isn't quite possible at the moment). I simply can’t convince myself to agree with what my school textbook says.

Is this a wrong sentence then? (To me, it doesn’t seem so.)

> I dislike to go there.

And this the correct one?

> I dislike going there.

My question is: **Can *to*-infinitives ever be used after *dislike*?**

Comment: Both the to-infinitive and the gerund are commonly used with both *like* and *dislike*. For the verb *to go*, the Ngram viewer finds that the infinitive is preferred with *like*; the gerund, with *dislike*. Go figure.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the info! It's finally a relief. I'm so glad to learn that my suspicion turned out to be right.

Comment: @deadrat I'd question the first part of your comment. In my experience, _like_ is commonly used with both gerunds and infinitives (Ngrams bears this out), but _dislike_ is only commonly used with gerunds. _Dislike to do_ is borderline ungrammatical to me, and the gerund construction is more than seven times as frequent in Ngrams as well. Of course, _dislike_ is on the decline in general—_don’t like_ is much more common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJaquet you're probably correct.

Comment: As a catenative verb, "dislike" licenses gerund-participial complements only.

Comment: If you can provide "several instances" then provide them. Questions should demonstrate your own research. Of course, by doing so  you're changing the impetus of your question, from that of contemporary English to historical English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Is *“I dislike to go there”* a wrong sentence?

**ᴛʟᴅʀ:**
Like *like*, historically *dislike* took a *ᴛᴏ*-infinitive not an *-ɪɴɢ* verb, but over the last century common usage has swapped those two preferences and now the *ᴛᴏ*-infinitive sounds distinctly odd to the modern ear. At the same time, *dislike* has also been replaced by *don’t like*, so even *dislike* seems old.

---

Your question is more interesting than those who have so far answered or commented upon it seem to credit. That’s because this is one of those many areas where English has changed notably within a comparatively short time.

Specifically, the dominant sort of (non-finite) clause complement following *dislike* before the Twentieth Century was of the same sort as the one following *like*: both habitually took a verb in the *ᴛᴏ*-infinitive not in its *-ɪɴɢ* form.

Although if one tries hard enough, one can find a few *dislike ᴠᴇʀʙing* examples from before the American Civil War, these are scarce in comparison with how easy it is to find cases of *dislike* + *ᴛᴏ*-infinitive.

### The Plot Thickens

Here’s [a plot of *dislike to have* against *dislike having*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dislike+to+have%2Cdislike+having&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdislike%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdislike%20having%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google N-Gram plotting dislike to have, dislike having]

And here [a plot *dislike to be* against *dislike being*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dislike+to+have%2Cdislike+having&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdislike%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdislike%20having%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

### Older Examples

Here are some older examples from back when it was common:

> - Some **dislike to have** it in the house anywhere. All salted provision must
>     be watched, and kept under the brine. (Simmons, 1796)
> - Sinners **dislike to go and work** in God's vineyard, because of their
>     prevailing love to carnal ease. Spiritual sloth is so sweet a sin,
>     that the carnal heart is always in love with it. (1843)
> - I very much **wish to walk** there, and particularly **dislike to** go in quite
>     by myself. (1845)
> - I certainly should **dislike to go** into another Regt. To be sure I could
>     worry through 11 months most any way but I **would rather go** with the Boys. (Civil War Journal of William Ray)
> - I **dislike to go** up there very much, the place is so lonely but I feel
>     that duty demands of me to go even at the sacrifice of my own feelings.
>     (Diary of Henrietta Baker Embree, 1856–1861)
> - My old master and mistress to Virginia, had often threatened to sell me
>     to the negro buyer from Georgia, for any trifling offence, and in order
>     to **make me dislike to go** there, they would tell me I should have to eat
>     cotton seed, and make indigo, ... (William Grimes, Civil War period)
> - It has pleased those philosophers who **dislike to have** an effect presented
>     to their consideration without a cause duly assigned and certified, **to
>     ascribe** my fragile health to a consumptive habit, and, having afflicted
>     me with a ‘pulmonary disease ... (Gillies, 1829)
> - I **hope to be able to see** you again, but fear not as I **dislike to be asking**
>     for leave while here, and when I get orders it will be necessary to obey
>     them at once. If I **can go to see** you without any neglect of duty, I will. (Pender, Civil War Letters)
> - A novel would scarcely be distinguished from a book of travels, if
>     loaded with a heavy commentary; and many readers not only **dislike to
>     have** their attention called to the bottom of the page, but care little
>     for the explanation thus offered them. (Rémusat, 1827)
> - How I **disliked to go and leave** Julian but I must not seem negligent of Mr Thomas now when he is so much troubled. (Journal of Ella Gertrude Clanton Thomas, 1848–1889)

As you see, *dislike to* isn’t the only thing that reads a bid odd in those Nineteenth Century examples.

### Newer Examples

Here are a couple from only a century ago, by which time it was already rare:

> - Primarily because they instinctively **dislike to be** bossed. All men
>     **dislike to be** bossed, employer and employee alike. (Filene, 1922)
> - Much of the Great Ones might be learnt in such regions, and those with
>     their blood might inherit little memories very useful to a seeker. They
>     might not know their parentage, for the gods so **dislike to be known**
>     among men that none can be found who has seen their faces wittingly;
>     a thing which Carter realised even as he sought to scale Kadath. (Lovecraft, 1920)

In contrast, the examples from the past fifty years of *dislike* + *ᴛᴏ*-infinitive are quite uncommon. Most that I could come up with have mitigating factors such as parallelism or established idioms which may have overridden the current instinct to use an *-ɪɴɢ* complement.

> - For their own use when travelling they make simple shelters as night approaches, because they **dislike to get** wet. (Lumholtz, 2012)
> - Quaint is a word that I **dislike to hear** in descriptions of flowers, but this yellow torenia is quaint. (Elizabeth Lawrence, 1997)
> - Why do we so dislike to be told that the Jews are the chosen people? (Badham, 1998)
> - As much as I **dislike to have the jury running** in and out I think this
>     is important. It ought to be given a full airing in open court. (McDonald 1970)
> - We read in Ovid and elsewhere how much the gods **dislike to hear men boasting** of their merits: they react as a human aristocracy would do, with resent and fear for their privileges. (Northrup Frye, 1970)
> - In the first place, one **would dislike to have other persons break**
>     the promises which they had made to oneself whenever they found it
>     inconvenient to fulfil them. But this presupposes a certain aversion in
>     oneself, which one no doubt correctly ... (Broad, 1985)
> - We **like to see** a lady like a town-clock regulating her motions by the progress of the sun; but we **dislike to see** a lady like a *town-clock*, governing the movements of the whole neighborhood. (Sam Atkinson,1968)
> - If asked why, in that case, we do not emigrate to Portugal, he replies that capitalists **fear to send** their capital into countries in which they are not resident, and **dislike to go and settle** in foreign countries themselves. (Cannan, 1964)
> - They speak jeeringly of our wilderness of deceased elms, and sneer at
>     our defunct magnolias. We **hate to cast** a reflection on the house, but
>     we also **dislike to be played** for Chinamen when we are no such thing. (Nye & Halsey, 1972)
> - I **dislike to think** that it must take place before your return, but I suppose it must, if you are not coming for so long. (Heffernan & Stecker, 1993)
> - He assumes people **like to be better paid** than others, and **dislike to be
>     paid** worse. (2007)

### So how come anybody ever still uses this?

I suspect that the recent examples using the infinitive owe their existence to such factors as:

- idioms like *to come/go/try and do something*
- avoidance of having multiple stacked *-ɪɴɢ* forms in the complement of *dislike*
- desired parallelism with other verbs elsewhere in the sentence

For example, this rewrite breaks the parallelism between *like* and *dislike*:

- He assumes people **like to be** paid better than others, and **dislike being** paid worse.

This rewrite becomes clumsy with two *-ɪɴɢ* forms fighting with each other:

- We read in Ovid and elsewhere how much the gods **dislike hearing men boasting** of their merits....

Which would be better written *dislike hearing men boast*.

Here again the twinned *-ɪɴɢ* verbs seem awkward in a putative rewrite:

- ... and **dislike going and settling** in foreign countries themselves.
- How I **disliked going and leaving** Julian but I must not seem negligent of Mr Thomas now when he is so much troubled.

The combined *to X and Y* verbs may not fare so well upon rewrite. For example, consider:

- If you truly **dislike to even try and make** yourself a sandcastle, you haven’t lived yet.

The rewrite may not even be grammatical:

- If you truly **dislike even ?trying and making** yourself a sandcastle, you haven’t lived yet.

These would likely be better:

- If you wouldn’t even **like to try and make** yourself a sandcastle, you haven’t lived yet.
- If you truly **don’t even like trying to make** yourself a sandcastle, you haven’t lived yet.

---

### Disliking *dislike*

Which brings us around to one more factor in play here.  Usage of [the verb *dislike* has seriously declined](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disliked%2Cdid+not+like&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisliked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdid%20not%20like%3B%2Cc0) in just the past few decades:

[image: plot of disliked agains did not like]

That means that you will naturally find fewer instances of *dislike* since it is being replaced by *don’t like*.

---

## But wait! What’s the answer to my question?

The broad but not especially useful answer to your question is that one cannot say that your original sentence  is categorically wrong, given that it was once common:

1. I dislike to go there.

However, people who don’t read much might erroneously think it wrong, since its form is one virtually unseen in this millennium save under extenuating literary circumstances, ones you would never expect to encounter scattered amongst the *post*-literate Post-It™ notes of today’s Internet chatter.

So while it is not “technically” wrong, given that your sentence uses a grammatical construction so rarely seen in present day writing, you would therefore do well to avoid the verb’s *ᴛᴏ*-infinitive here in favor of its *-ɪɴɢ* form:

2. I dislike going there.

But even that seems rather stiff and formal for casual use.  In normal conversation you would simply say either of these:

3. I don’t like to go there.
4. I don’t like going there.

There is no notable difference in meaning between three and four.  Three is more common than four, but this trend is falling:

[image: ngram of do not like to go,do not like going]

Comment: ooh! It's really helpful. So well-researched, precise, and detailed. I really loved all the explanations.

After reading the comments, I felt that things have changed over time. to dislike must have become obsolete. No wonder people think of it as "wrong" altogether! In modern times, it is used very sparingly. Thanks for all the information! I am very inquisitive (sometimes overly curious about small things which most people would never have thoughts upon) and this answer satisfies my curiosity fully.

Answer (score 0):

The amusing situation is that this brings up a category of verbs that are sometimes discussed separately in schools as "preference" verbs.  The instruction tends to be that verbs of preference are followed by -ing verbs.  As was rightly pointed out, "like" is a preference, and yet it does not follow that rule.

In truth, like so many things in English, the rules are always made to be broken.  What is certainly fact at the moment is that "dislike" is only followed by -ing constructions.  (It can, as the [Cambrdige dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing) site notes, have another subject introduced before the -ing verb.)

I hope you don't dislike finding this out!

Comment: While the infinitive does sound odd to me in almost all circumstances, there nonetheless do exist recent examples that work the other way. I’ve tried to explain why I think they might be happening based on this question having been asked on [elu.se] not on [ell.se].